# what happens in this block of code?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

What happens when I do this? When I remove the first initialization to "boo1", it prints boo2 but now it still prints nothing. Does this mean that the pointer allocate a random memory and assign "boo1" value to it and now I can't access it or what?

```
string *p;
*p="boo1"; 
p=new string;
*p="boo2";
cout << *p;   //prints nothing
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: What do you mean "undefined"? Like we can't expect/know what happens?

Comment: I mean it's not specified in the standard. It's completely up to the runtime system implementation. It could work, crash, format your HD or send you 50 years into the past.

Comment: The second call was made to understand what happens in the first one. This is not a usable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line 1: "p" contains random value, i.e. refers to random memory address.

line 2: random memory block referred by "*p" is interpreted as string instance. This instance is assigned by "boo1".

Try so:

```
string *p = new string;
*p = "boo1";
cout << *p << '\n';
*p = "boo2";
cout << *p << '\n';
delete p;
```

Remember that:

1. std::string is not the same as stupid char[] array!
2. All pointers must be assigned before usage!
3. All "new" must have corresponding "delete"!

Comment: That's my question,I wanted to know whether or not it refers to a random memory, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a string as pointer ( string *p ), you must allocate memory for it,

so the correct way to do the job is:

```
string *p = new string;
*p = "boo1";
cout << *p << '\n';
*p = "boo2";
cout << *p << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, however why not using a reference, it seems more convenient in your case.
Something like :

```
std::string p;
p = "boo1";
std::cout << p << std::endl;
p = "boo2";
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

Regards,

Michel.